# Filter and subset function only hiding rows, not deleting?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr

I'm trying to delete certain trials in a fictional experiment, but the filter/subset functions only appear to be hiding the rows, not getting rid of them entirely.

eg. using the iris sample data:

```
> xtabs(Sepal.Length~Species,data=iris,)
Species
    setosa versicolor  virginica 
     250.3      296.8      329.4 

> iris2 <- subset(iris, Species!="virginica")
> xtabs(Sepal.Length~Species,data=iris2)
Species
    setosa versicolor  virginica 
     250.3      296.8        0.0 

> iris3 <- filter(iris, Species=="virginica")
> xtabs(Sepal.Length~Species,data=iris3)
Species
    setosa versicolor  virginica 
       0.0        0.0      329.4
```

The data frame appears to have the right number of observations in the global environment but it's still keeping the filtered/subsetted out factors around. I can't use any sort of "remove NA" or "remove 0" features either, because they're not 0, they're just not visible. How can I get rid of these rows entirely??

Answer (score 0):

Filtering the dataframe doesn't change the number of factor levels.

```
iris %>% 
   filter(Species == "virginica") %>%
   pull(Species) %>%
   levels(.)

[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

If you don't want to aggregate with all levels, you need to drop the levels without data.

```
iris3 <- filter(iris, Species=="virginica") %>%
  mutate(Species = fct_drop(Species))

xtabs(Sepal.Length~Species,data=iris3)

Species
virginica 
    329.4
```